# two plays with two different host in same playbook with dependency

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-2.x

Senario:

```
1. I need to run two plays in a single playbook.
2. The second play should run after the first play.
3. The first play create few instance and update the inventory file by making new group.
4. Second play uses the updated group and install few packages.
```

Problem: If I am running both plays separately it is success.
But, i need them in same scripts.

The problem i think is both play executing in parallel.

And thanks in advance.

```
---
 - name: ec2
   hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   roles:
   - launchEc2
 - hosts: ansible
   gather_facts: Fasle
   become: yes   
   roles:
   - python
```

OUTPUT:

```
PLAY [ec2] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [launchEc2 : include_vars] ************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [launchEc2 : Launch new ec2 instance] *************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [launchEc2 : Add ec2 ip to the hostgroup] *********************************
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item={.....})

TASK [launchEc2 : wait for SSh to come up] *************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={.....})

PLAY [ansible] *****************************************************************

TASK [python : install python] *************************************************
skipping: [34.203.228.19]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=5    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0   
34.203.228.19              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you manually update host file instead of using `add_host`.

Comment: I am using lineinfile to update the host.... can there be any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible loads inventory before processing playbook.

In your case the second play has the same inventory as it was before modification in the first play.

Generally when you provision cloud hosts you may want to use `add_host` to dynamically add new hosts to in memory inventory, so they are available to subsequent plays.

You may also try to call `meta: refresh_inventory` after your inventory modification, but I'm not sure wether it work with updating static inventory.

Comment: i tried with 'add_host' now second play is able to execute but it shows **skipping**

Comment: add playbook snippet and log output to your _original_ question.

Comment: should `meta: refresh_inventory` should be added before second play ?

Comment: thanks @Konstantin Suvorov adding `add_host` worked but, new ip's are not adding to inventory file...